# How to get fragment index from within itself?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I have 3 fragments that are generated from the same class file.  These three fragments exist within a ViewPager and a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

They are in sliding tabs.  They are created once and never dismissed or deleted or go out of memory.

The app works fine so far, but I need to figure out how to make the fragments have knowledge of their own index (1,2, or 3).

Is there some code like:

```
int myIndex = summonTheAllKnowingThing.getWhatFragmentThisIsPlease();
```

That I can add somewhere in the following code?

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private boolean isDone = false;


    EditText persons_name;

    Spinner disc1_spinner;
    Spinner disc2_spinner;
    Spinner disc3_spinner;

    Spinner fee1_spinner;
    Spinner fee2_spinner;

    EditText custom_disc;

    EditText custom_fee;

    Button doneButton;


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static BlankFragment newInstance() {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        doneButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // getView().findViewById(R.id.

        persons_name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.NAME);

        disc1_spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.DISC1);
        disc2_spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.DISC2);
        disc3_spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.DISC3);

        custom_disc = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.customDISC);
        custom_fee = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.customFEE);



    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.doneButton:

                if MainActivity.is1Done
                doneButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                MainActivity.name1 = persons_name.getText().toString();

                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is to pass the index while creating the fragment in pager adapter as in

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return BlankFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
```

and **BlankFragment** would be

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        private int myIndex; //<-- access it for getting its index
        //.. some other variables
        public BlankFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        public static BlankFragment newInstance(int indexInPager) {
            BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("index",indexInPager);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           myIndex = getArguments().getInt("index");
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
           doneButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
           doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
           return v;
        }
        //.. some other code
  }
```

Comment: I'm not using "someOtherFragment" ... can I say return BlankFragment.newInstance(0) .... and Blank(1),  (2) ?

Comment: Thanks buddy!  You gave me enough information to get this to work...I made the private int myIndex NOT static, and changed myIndex = indexinPager to fragment.myIndex = indexinPager.  And also, of course used BlankFragment for all cases in the getItem method. THANK YOU!

Comment: Well, i've updated the answer for your requirement :)